# How to get the CPU usage of a Hyper-V host for the last hour?

Tags: powershell, monitoring, hyper-v

I want to get performance data of a Hyper-V host for the last hour.

In VMware ESXi there was vSphere API through which we can get history data.

For Hyper-V is there any of such API or method by which we can get history data?

For example if we trigger a command at 10:00 AM the is it possible to get last 1 hour (09:00 AM to 10:00 AM ) CPU usage of the Hyper-V host?
Does Hyper-V log this somewhere?
Untill now I am able to get performance data for current time using `wmi`, but this doesnt't give me informations about past data.

Comment: How about using Performance Monitor to log the data?

Comment: @vonPryz thanks for the answer. But can you please help me to get some powershell command to download the performance monitor log.

Comment: The log needs to be set up for gathering data, it doesn't exist automatically. When there's data to be analyzed, the `*-Counter` cmdlets can be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at these excellent articles.

- [Monitoring Performance](http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Retrieving-Windows-performance-data-in-PowerShell/(offset)/3)
- [pcmag's Article](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2018/02/07/performance-counters-in-powershell.aspx)
- [Technet Tutorials](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872428.aspx)

All these tasks are done using the `Get-Counter` cmdlet -> [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-counter?view=powershell-5.1)